# When creating relationships in MVC4 EF CodeFirst, why do we need to include both Object and ObjectId?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

For example, when relating Cards to Sets, I have:

```
public class Card
{

    public virtual int CardId { get; set; }

    // belongs to a Set
    public virtual int SetId { get; set; }
    public virtual Set Set { get; set; }
 }
```

Why do I need both Set and SetId?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to set it. You can just specify "Set" as a virtual object so it can be overwritten with the navigational property at runtime. The Entity Framework will automatically create the foreign key "SetId" on the table, even though you won't have access to it from your object domain model.

You don't need to set it, but I personally like having access to the underlying foreign key id on my object, since I can specify a relationship with an int instead of having to instantiate the related object.

**Edit: Adding example code**

Having the following classes:

```
public class Card
    {
        public virtual int CardId { get; set; }

        // belongs to a Set
        public virtual int SetId { get; set; }
        public virtual Set Set { get; set; }
    }

    public class Set
    {
        public int SetId { get; set; }
        public string SetName { get; set; }
    }
```

I can either do something like this:

```
    var context = new Context(); //Db Code-First Context

    var set = context.Sets.First(s => s.SetName == "Clubs"); //Get the "Clubs" set object

    //Assign the set to the card
    var newCard = new Card();
    newCard.Set = set; 

    //Save the object to the databae
    context.Cards.Add(newCard);
    context.SaveChanges();
```

Or do something like this:

```
//Assign the set ID to the card
var newCard = new Card();
newCard.SetId = 4; 

//Save the object to the databae
context.Cards.Add(newCard);
context.SaveChanges();
```

And the object would be stored the same way.

Imagine that you are posting a ViewModel to a controller. It's easier to pass the selected Id from a Dropdown list on the view and not the whole object.

Comment: Can you provide an example for your answer?

Comment: Sure, Give me a couple of minutes and I'll update it with some code

Comment: @Mr.Young example added to response :)